# How to include makefiles dynamically?

Tags: makefile, aix

Is it possible to include Makefiles dynamically? For example depending on some environment variable? I have the following Makefiles:

```
makefile
app1.1.mak
app1.2.mak
```

And there is an environment variable `APP_VER` which could be set to 1.1.0.1, 1.1.0.2, 1.2.0.1, 1.2.0.2.
But there will be only two different makefiles for 1.1 and 1.2 lines.

I have tried to write the following Makefile:

```
MAK_VER=$$(echo $(APP_VER) | sed -e 's/^\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*$$/\1/')  
include makefile$(MAK_VER).mak  

all: PROD  
        echo MAK_VER=$(MAK_VER)
```

But it does not work:

```
$ make all
"makefile$(echo", line 0: make: Cannot open makefile$(echo
make: Fatal errors encountered -- cannot continue.
```

**UPDATE:**

As far as I understand `make` includes files before it calculates macros.
That's why it tries to execute the following statement

```
include makefile.mak
```

instead of

```
include makefile1.1.mak
```

Comment: Do you mean that `APP_VER` might be set to "1.1" or "1.2", or that it might be set to "1.1version" or "1.2vladimir"?

Comment: ...And is the "simple makefile" the same as `makefile`, or another?

Comment: @Beta APP_VER which could be set to 1.1.0.1, 1.1.0.2, 1.2.0.1, 1.2.0.2. But there will be only two different makefiles for 1.1 and 1.2 lines.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems: your method of obtaining the version is too complicated, and your `include` line has a flaw. Try this:

```
include app$(APP_VER).mak
```

If `APP_VER` is an environmental variable, then this will work. If you also want to include the makefile called `makefile` (that is, if `makefile` is not the one we're writing), then try this:

```
include makefile app$(APP_VER).mak
```

Please note that this is considered a *bad idea*. If the makefile depends on environmental variables, it will work for some users and not others, which is considered bad behavior.

**EDIT:**

This should do it:

```
MAK_VER := $(subst ., ,$(APP_VER))
MAK_VER := $(word 1, $(MAK_VER)).$(word 2, $(MAK_VER))

include makefile app$(MAK_VER).mak
```

Comment: Please read an update. APP_VER can be set to 1.1.0.1, 1.1.0.2, 1.2.0.1, 1.2.0.2, etc. But I need different makefiles for 1.1 and 1.2 lines.

Comment: Unfortunately my version of make(for AIX) does not support either subst or word functions.

Comment: @Vladimir Bezugliy: Does it support `$(shell ...)`?

Comment: No. It does not support. I decided to use following approach: INNER_MAKEFILE=$(MAKEDIR)/makefile_$(APP_VER).mak
include $(INNER_MAKEFILE)

Comment: Good technique with the '`:=`' if you are using GNU Make.  On AIX, you are stuck with either demanding that the environment variable is set, or with some technique such as linking the correct version-specific makefile to a fixed name which is always included.  (That works well unless you switch between the two versions all the time, but then you have to clean up stuff that was built for the other version anyway, so fixing the makefile too is not dreadfully onerous.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MAK_VER=$(shell echo $(APP_VER) | sed -e 's/^\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*$$/\1/')
MAK_FILE=makefile$(MAK_VER).mak

include $(MAK_FILE)

all:
    echo $(MAK_VER)
    echo $(MAK_FILE)
```

Comment: $ export APP_VER=1.1; make all
"makefile", line 0: make: Cannot open makefile
make: Fatal errors encountered -- cannot continue.

Comment: The makefile posted above works (doesn't generate the errors you're showing).  Without getting into the details of your specific situation, the key parts are the first three lines that collects the output of the shell command into a variable, creates the makefile name "dynamically", then includes it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Modifying the outline solution

Have four makefiles:

- makefile
- app1.1.mak
- app1.2.mak
- appdummy.mak

The `app.dummy.mak` makefile can be empty - a symlink to /dev/null if you like.  Both app.1.1.mak and app.1.2.mak are unchanged from their current content.

The main makefile changes a little:

```
MAK_VER = dummy
include makefile$(MAK_VER).mak  

dummy:  
        ${MAKE} MAK_VER=$$(echo $(APP_VER) | sed -e 's/^\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*$$/\1/') all

all: PROD
        ...as now...
```

If you type `make`, it will read the (empty) dummy makefile, and then try to build the `dummy` target because it appears first.  To build the dummy target, it will run `make` again, with `APP_VER=1.1` or `APP_VER=1.2` on the command line:

```
make APP_VER=1.1 all
```

Macros set on the command line cannot be changed within the makefile, so this overrides the line in the makefile. The second invocation of `make`, therefore, will read the correct version-specific makefile, and then build `all`.

This technique has limitations, most noticeably that it is fiddly to arrange for each and every target to be treated like this.  There are ways around it, but usually not worth it.

---

#### Project organization

More seriously, I think you need to review what you're doing altogether.  You are, presumably, using a version control system (VCS) to manage the source code.  Also, presumably, there are some (significant) differences between the version 1.1 and 1.2 source code.  So, to be able to do a build for version 1.1, you have to switch from the version 1.1 maintenance branch to the version 1.2 development branch, or something along those lines.  So, why isn't the makefile just versioned for 1.1 or 1.2?  If you switch between versions, you need to clean out all the derived files (object files, libraries, executables, etc) that may have been built with the wrong source.  You have to change the source code over.  So why not change the makefile too?

#### A build script to invoke make

I also observe that since you have the environment variable APP_VER driving your process, that you can finesse the problem by requiring a standardized 'make invoker' that sorts out the APP_VER value and invokes `make` correctly.  Imagine that the script is called `build`:

```
#!/bin/sh
: ${APP_VER:=1.2.0.1}  # Latest version is default
case $APP_VER in
[0-9].[0-9].*)
    MAK_VER=`echo $APP_VER | sed -e 's/^\(...\).*/\1/'`
    ;;
*)  echo "`basename $0 .sh`: APP_VER ($APP_VER) should start with two digits followed by dots" 1>&2;
    exit 1;;
esac
exec make MAK_VER=$MAK_VER "$@"
```

This script validates that APP_VER is set, giving an appropriate default if it is not.  It then processes that value to derive the MAK_VER (or errors out if it is incorrect).  You'd need to modify that test after you reach version 10, of course, since you are planning to be so successful that you will reach double-digit version numbers in due course.

Given the correct version information, you can now invoke your makefile with any command line arguments.

The makefile can be quite simple:

```
MAK_VER = dummy

include app$(MAK_VER).mak  

all: PROD
        ...as now...
```

The appdummy.mak file now contains a rule:

```
error:
        echo "You must invoke this makefile via the build script" 1>&2
        exit 1
```

It simply points out the correct way to do the build.

Note that you can avoid the APP_VER environment variable if you keep the product version number under the VCS in a file, and the script then reads the version number from the file.  And there could be all sorts of other work done by the script, ensuring that correct tools are installed, other environment variables are set, and so on.